# How can I use a variable outside of event handler?

Tags: jquery

I have select section in html page with id "select" and I create a JQuery code for example :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", function () {
        var text = $("#select").val();
    });
    allert(text);
});
```

but this code not work . How can I call "text" out of function?

EDIT (HTML Code):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myjquerycode.js"></script>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="select">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can achieve this by defining `text` outside of the `change` event handler, although alerting it at the point you are is redundant as the value will always be undefined.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make any sense. the on('change',...) sets up an event handler that doesn't execute until a change event occurs. The alert you have after setting up the event handler will execute right away so the event hasn't occurred.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When select value change my code alert select value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe id is wrong. Check your id.

Also checkout https://api.jquery.com/change/

For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").change(function() {
    var text = $("#select").val();
    alert(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="select">
```

**EDIT**

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  var str = "";
  $("select option:selected").each(function() {
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
  $("div").text(str);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and call it when you need it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getSelect() {
    return $("#select").val();
  }

  $("#select").change(function() {
    alert(getSelect()); // This will alert you anytime you change it
  });

  var selectValue = getSelect(); // You can get its value outside wherever else you need it

});
```

Comment: You correct the syntax problem but it's not an answer of "How can I use var in out of function?"

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear when you want to use the value

Here is how to alert the value of the select when the select changes

```
$(function() {
    $("#select").on("change", function() {
      var text = $(this).val();
      alert(text);
    });
});
```

Elsewhere after the select exists in the DOM:

```
alert($("#select").val());
```

or

```
$("#select").change(); // trigger the already existing handler
```